# How to create an intermediate canvas in delphi?

Tags: delphi, canvas, handle

I have an application where I need to print a graphic to a temporary TCanvas. My problem is that I can't refresh this canvas once I've drawn on it. Here's what I do:

```
var
  BitMap : TBitmap;
  WindowHandle : HWND;
  ScreenDC,bufferDC : HDC;
 bufferBitmap : HBitmap;
  tempcanvas : TCanvas;
begin
  windowhandle := 0;
  tempcanvas := TCanvas.Create;
  screenDC := GetwindowDC(WindowHandle);
  BufferDC := CreateCOmpatibleDC(ScreenDC);
  TempCanvas.Handle := BufferDC;
  BufferBitmap := CreateCompatibleBitmap(ScreenDC, GetDeviceCaps(ScreenDC, HORZRES),
                                  GetDeviceCaps(ScreenDC,VERTRES));
  SelectObject(BufferDC,BufferBitmap);
  TempCanvas.Handle := getDeviceContext(windowHandle);
(...)
```

The Canvas does not get refreshed when I move out of scope and then return with a new procedure call. Is there a clever way to do this with the globals I'm currently using, or do I need to use local variables, and if so, how to do that?

Comment: I cannot understand your final paragraph. I don't know what you are trying to achieve, and how your code fails. An SSCCE and some details as to how the code fails to meet your expectations would help.

Comment: The above code sets a handle on a temporary canvas
After this I print a graphics object to the canvas and use CopyRect to move it from here and to its final destination. The issue now is that, while this works the first time around, the canvas does not reset and the next time I run the procedure, the graphics of the first iteration are produced again

Comment: You declare a bitmap variable that you don't use. If you used it, you wouldn't need any of the other code you've shown. Each time you create a bitmap object, it starts with a blank canvas.

Comment: Just instantiate `TBitmap` and save a lot of trouble.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I couldn't get the locally declared TBitmap to work because of an error in a proprietary software module that has now been identified